# BigQuery Operator in Airflow not reading sql as raw file

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

my aim here is to store sql code in GCS and pass into the 'sql' parameter using the  Bigquery Operator for my daily ETL processes.

My error is

```
Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'invalidQuery', 'location': 'query', 'message': 'Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "/" at [1:1]'}
```

The issue I currently have is that the sql code, which is a simple

```
Select * 
FROM 
table
```

is having the newline `/n` being read as part of the sql file, so it's failing as an invalid query. When I read the sql file in python, it's being read as follows

```
'SELECT * \nFROM \n    `table` as test\n'
```

My task is as follows

```
t1 = BigQueryOperator(
  task_id='bigquery_test',
  sql= '/home/airflow/.../filename.sql ',
  destination_dataset_table = destination_table,
  write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
  use_legacy_sql=False,
  dag=dag,
)
```

I'm assuming this is something to do with how the sql param is set up in airflow but I cannot wrap my head around what I need to do to get around this issue.

any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to further contribute to the community, I am adding and complement to @Pentium10's answer.

According to the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.html), the `sql` parameter should receive a string representing a sql statement or a `.sql` templated file with the query you want to run. This file should be stored within the folder `/home/airflow/gcs/data` because this folder ***stores the data that tasks produce and use***. Besides, it is ***mounted on all worker nodes***, [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_bucket). Therefore, you should reference your templated `.sql` file (not the whole path), as follows:

```
t1 = BigQueryOperator(
  task_id='bigquery_test',
  sql= 'filename.sql',
  destination_dataset_table = destination_table,
  write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
  use_legacy_sql=False,
  dag=dag,
)
```

In addition, I must point out that in case you want to reference a templated `sql` file in another folder, for example a sub-folder within `/home/airflow/gcs/data`, you must specify the `template_searchpath` parameter. It specifies the folder where Jinja will look for the templates, [link](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/models/dag.html?highlight=template_searchpath). Below is the syntax how it would be,

with models.DAG(
'bigqueryoperator_dag',
template_searchpath='/home/airflow/gcs/data/bigqueryoperator/',
default_args=DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS) as dag:

```
bqo = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='bigqueryoperator_templated_sql',
    sql='sample_query_tempalte.sql',
    use_legacy_sql=False,
)
```

Notice that the file `sample_query_tempalte.sql` is located within the sub-folder `/home/airflow/gcs/data/bigqueryoperator/`.

Comment: @Tristan, in case you found this information useful. Please, consider accepting and upvoting the answer.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

> Expected end of input but got "/" at [1:1]

Your problem is the 3rd line:

It says the first char is `/` that's your path's first char.

```
t1 = BigQueryOperator(
  task_id='bigquery_test',
  sql= '/home/airflow/.../filename.sql ',
```

instead of passing a string of path, **you need to read the contents of the file**, and pass the contents of the file.

Comment: How we can pass a parameters like table names and some hard coded values in sql file. Can you please help me